# Transform sf multipolygon with 1 feature into sf multipolygon with 2 features for each non-intersecting polygon in R

Tags: r, polygon, sf

I have an sf multipolygon made up of two non-intersecting polygons. They look like this:

[image]

But my sf object is stored as a multipolygon with 1 feature, so I cannot evaluate the non-intersecting polygons separately.

[image]

Is there an sf command that will transform the multipolygon with 1 feature into a multipolygon with 2 features (for each of the non-intersecting polygons)?

Answer (score 0):

You have a spatial data frame like this, 1 feature (MULTIPOLYGON) and 3 fields:

```
> dd
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 3 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XYZM
Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 34 ymax: 34
z_range:       zmin: 0 zmax: 0
m_range:       mmin: 0 mmax: 0
CRS:           NA
  A B C                       geometry
1 1 2 3 MULTIPOLYGON ZM (((0 0 0 0,...
```

If you cast to POLYGON then that will split the MULTIPOLYGONS up into individual POLYGON features - in my case there's three POLYGON features. The other attributes are replicated:

```
> st_cast(dd,"POLYGON")
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XYZM
Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 34 ymax: 34
CRS:           NA
    A B C                       geometry
1   1 2 3 POLYGON ZM ((0 0 0 0, 10 0 ...
1.1 1 2 3 POLYGON ZM ((12 12 0 0, 22 ...
1.2 1 2 3 POLYGON ZM ((24 24 0 0, 34 ...
Warning message:
In st_cast.sf(dd, "POLYGON") :
  repeating attributes for all sub-geometries for which they may not be constant
```

Now if you really want those 3 POLYGON features to be 3 MULTIPOLYGON features then cast to MULTIPOLYGON, which works on each one separately:

```
> st_cast(st_cast(dd,"POLYGON"),"MULTIPOLYGON")
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XYZM
Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 34 ymax: 34
CRS:           NA
    A B C                       geometry
1   1 2 3 MULTIPOLYGON ZM (((0 0 0 0,...
1.1 1 2 3 MULTIPOLYGON ZM (((12 12 0 ...
1.2 1 2 3 MULTIPOLYGON ZM (((24 24 0 ...
Warning message:
In st_cast.sf(dd, "POLYGON") :
  repeating attributes for all sub-geometries for which they may not be constant
```

Normally you wouldn't need to do this, the POLYGON class being good enough at this point for most things, but you did ask...

Comment: Thank you. I can see I got my multipolygon and polygon terminology mixed up. Thank you for providing me with everything I needed!!!

Comment: If you got everything that you needed then please accept the answer!